# install 3rd party jar maven with resources

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin

I have a jar file that reads a text file and gives some output. Text file is located **where the jar file is located**. I needed to load that jar to maven project as a 3rd party jar. So I used

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

And added the dependency accordingly. But when I run the maven project after building I get a File Not Found Exception when maven project try to call that 3rd party jar. Where should I place that text file in order to be referenced by 3rd party jar.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

below your resource tag in maven xml , try add

```
<includes>
  <include>**/*.txt</include>
</includes>
```

It may work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added that but it does not work. After adding my web app pom build looks like follows.      <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.txt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>webApp</finalName>
    </build>

Comment: try use unpack in your pom, then repack the 3rd jar : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html